# Object doesn't support this property or method when copy data between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA and need your help on the following issue. Thanks in advance.

I have two workbooks for foreign currency prices. One workbook contains the Bid prices and another contains the Ask prices and I want to copy the data from Ask price workbook to Bid price workbook. Because I have many of such Bid and Ask workbooks for different pairs so I need VBA to automate the process. What I have done with my code so far is:

1. open the Bid price workbook
2. get the path and filename of Bid price workbook and based on this to get the filename and path for Ask price workbook
3. use the obtained filename and path to open the Ask price workbook
   (my existing code works fine up to this point)
4. copy all the data from Ask price workbook to Bid price workbook 
   step 4 is where I have stucked and got the "object doesn't support this propoerty or method error".

I hope you guys can help out on resolving this. Many thanks. Below is the code I have.
The link for the two workbooks is here:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2YYk8FCgGVkeVBMYmFMUGt6amc&usp=sharing

```
Sub getAskPrice()

Dim currentWb As Workbook
Dim openWb As Workbook
Dim currentWs As String
Dim openWs As String
Dim path As String
Dim targetPath As String

Set currentWb = ActiveWorkbook
currentWs = ActiveSheet.Name
Range("K1") = currentWs

path = ThisWorkbook.FullName
targetPath = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(path, "Bid", "Ask")
Range("K2") = targetPath

Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(targetPath)
openWs = ActiveSheet.Name

openWb.Sheets(openWs).Activate

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

currentWb.Activate

Range("H1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Regards,
MY

Comment: Your code works for me.......I tried it on two workbooks on my desktop.....each workbook contained a single worksheet.....the names of both sheets is *Sheet1*

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work on my computer

Comment: Very strange............I used your code **exactly,** but as I pointed out, both my workbooks are in the same folder and both workbooks had only a single sheet with the same sheetname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Selection.PasteSpecial` with `currentWb.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial`. Excel can be very picky on how you copy/paste cells. If you decide to copy from range to range, it requires for you to have the exact same range size. Whereas pasting to the sheet will let you have only one cell selected.

---

There are a few wildcards in your code, meaning you can't always know FOR SURE if your program will always act the same way. Using the **`Activesheet`** usually isn't recommended since it will be different every time the workbook was last saved with a different worksheet. Also, it's safer/neater to use **`Sheets` objects** rather than reference to its name everytime.

Here's a corrected version of your code (which now works perfectly) :)

```
Sub getAskPrice()

    Dim currentWb As Workbook, openWb As Workbook
    Dim currentWs As Worksheet, openWs As Worksheet
    Dim myPath As String, targetPath As String

    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set currentWs = currentWb.Sheets(1) 'change this "1" to the index number of the sheet you wanna work with

    myPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    targetPath = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myPath, "Bid", "Ask")

    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(targetPath)
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets(1) 'change this "1" to the index number of the sheet you wanna work with

    lastCol = openWs.Cells(1, openWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = openWs.Cells(openWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    openWs.Range(openWs.Cells(1, 1), openWs.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy


    currentWs.Range("H1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Note that I removed some of the useless lines.

Comment: `currentWs` is of type `String`, it doesn't have a `PasteSpecial` property or method.

Comment: Edited my answer, REALLY assumed it was a `Worksheet` object

Comment: Hi Bernard, thanks for pointing out this. After after the replacement, I still get the same problem. Any other suggestions? Thanks